# How to Speed Up SQLAlchemy.create_all() for unit testing

Tags: performance, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been trying to speed up the time to run all unit tests. As it turns out, majority of the time has been consumed at [SQLAlchemy.create_all()](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.0/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.create_all) in each test case's `setUp()` method.

There has been a few ideas I can think of to go about reducing the the time in the db setup (going with RAW SQL etc.) Before I delve into that approach, is there any better ways to speed things up?

Comment: why not to move it to setUpClass() / tearDownClass()?

Comment: why not to move it to setUpClass() / tearDownClass() to make sure the schema is only created once? Then have you setUp() / tearDown() to simply cleanup the data / junk, w/o rebuilding the schema.

Comment: You cannot `create_all` for each test. Remove the data after the test instead of drop the database.

Comment: @MOCKBA schemas have to be rebuilt/torn down in each test because it's may be slower to clean up the data without rebuilding the schemas (depending on how each test goes, DELTE FROM `table` may be slower than DROP TABLE `table`; CREATE TABLE `table` etc.)

Comment: @iurisilvio see my same answer above.

Comment: My tests runtime reduced in 80% when I changed to not drop/create tables all the time. `DELETE` is a cheap operation, compared to `DROP/CREATE`.

Comment: @iurisilvio Yes, actually your inspire me to use TRUNCATE that may be even faster to clean up! Is there any down side of not drop/create tables?

Comment: No down side. You just have to delete all data correctly. And do not trust primary keys starting in 1 for example.

Comment: @iurisilvio Cool thanks! I will give it a shot and report back the results. Btw, TRUNCATE will reset auto-increment columns, at least in MySQL.

Comment: another, IMHO more elegant solution, would be to have setUpClass() to generate the SQL file once based on your ORM definition (i.e. call create_all(), then `mysqldump --no-data ... > schema.sql`), then have setUp() to reload the file on each test and tearDown() to drop it (DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS). This way you don't have to deal with individual tables / TRUNCATE statements / information_schema.

Comment: @MOCKBA what you describe should work - though it may be cumbersome to implement. In my codebase, we have externalize the SQL DDL statements into a separate file and put it in source control. So that would simply it quite a bit.

Comment: @iurisilvio Just to report back the TRUNCATE approach did work although I need to fiddle around `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` to make it work. DROP TABLE approach won't need to deal with that. It makes sense to think TRUNCATE would be much faster than DROP TABLES/CREATE TABLES but in the end it doesn't seem to be the case - after all TRUNCATE behind the scene does all that at the same time has a limited scope (unless disabling foreign key constraint check). I may eventually end up using DROP/CREATE instead. But right now I am getting stuck at MySQL 1040 Error: Too many connections, for some reason. :(